# Pass element value by class instead of element name to jQuery.validator.addMethod

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I added a method validation plugin. But instead of passing Name, I need to pass element using class name as I don't know the `id` of the element rendered on page.

I tried created method and try to add to class using `addClassRules`.
Problem is value is not coming in `params[1]` is `undefined`.

I am not able to figure out how to pass element value to method.

```js
jQuery.validator.addMethod("MyMethod", function(value, element, params) {
  alert("First Value is " + params[0]);
  alert("Second Value is " + params[1]);
  return true; //for now

  //My code to do validation
}, '{0}'); //error message will come from params[0]

jQuery.validator.addClassRules("MyClassName", {
  required: true,
  MyMethod: ['My error message', $('#secCommonInformation .DOB').val()]
});
```

Comment: This isn't how the validation library works, nor can it work in this manner. I'd suggest reading the `validator.addMethod()` documentation if you are stuck: https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Comment: ok. Looks like I cannot pass selector value using class name.

Comment: It also has to do with using `$('#secCommonInformation .DOB').val()` as a parameter.  You cannot do this either.

Comment: It might help to show us a more complete demo.  Include your call to `.validate()` and HTML markup of the form.